# how to return all elements in a list

Tags: racket

I am doing a question where I am asked to return the first n elements from a list. I was able to do so by returning the first n elements in a list by creating another list that contains the first n elements in a list. Now I need to return all elements inside my new list, any ideas?

Comment: Please show your current code, along with examples of expected in- and output.

Comment: You mean, like the build-in `take` procedure? `(take '(1 2 3 4) 2)` => `'(1 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you don't want this but to return all elements of a list as a multiple value return you do this:

```
(apply values your-list)
```

But I expect you mean you need to return your created list. The last expression evaluated is what is returned so in your base case you evaluates your list and it will be returned.

Can't really say much more without you giving a tad more info about your solution or if you are required to have the element in the same order or not.